# Recreate form on viewPagerButtons click in jqgrid form editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid form editing in which i have to recreate the edit form when clicking `viewPagerButtons` button. Since i'm setting the `editable:false` dynamically using row values i have to recreate the form on every edit of row.

The form gets recreated when clicking on the row and clicking edit. But when using the `viewPagerButtons` click it doesn't.

//Code:

Something like,

```
//EditOptions {  
                 recreateForm: true,
                 viewPagerButtons: function onclick(){}
              }
```

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can't **recreate** editing form inside of `onclickPgButtons` or `afterclickPgButtons` callback because jqGrid just refill the data and not recreate the form on clicking on the navigation buttons in the form.

I would recommend you to use `editable: true` option for all columns which you want to makes "dynamically" editable. Instead of that you can **hide/show** conditionally some editing rows in the editing form inside of `beforeShowForm` and `afterclickPgButtons` callbacks. For example if you have column with `name: "myColumn"` then form editing contains the row with `id="tr_myColumn"`. The row contains both editing control and editing label. So you need conditionally call `$("#tr_myColumn").hide()` or `$("#tr_myColumn").show()`.

Alternatively you can just disable navigation buttons by usage `viewPagerButtons: false` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) of form editing.